# How can I set my Page styles and themes without using Page.Theme property?

Tags: c#, javascript, styles, themes, stylesheet

My page is designed using two style sheets, form.css and styles.css, and I want to dynamically set their path based on the domain name.

Here is the code I wrote to change them dynamically. It works, but flickering occurs before switching to the new theme, How can I set the page styles and themes without using the `Page.Theme` property?

**On Client Side**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function preloadFunc() {
        var foldername = '<%= theme%>';
        $('#lnkCssForm').attr('href', 'css/' + foldername + '/form.css');
        $('#lnkCssStyles').attr('href', 'css/' + foldername + '/styles.css');
    }
    window.onpaint = preloadFunc();
});
```

**On Server Side** (On Page preInit)

```
theme = Session["domainTheme"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you use javascript (and also on-dom-ready) for this? No wonder this causes "flicker". Why not output the path directly from the template/partial/whatever that outputs the head with the style?

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/<%= theme %>/form.css" media="all">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/<%= theme %>/styles.css" media="all">
</head>
```

And what is the reason you don't want to use `Page.Theme` for this? It's exactly what this is meant for...